# In C, why is NULL and 0 triggering an if statement

Tags: c, null, if-statement

I have a function that is called by

```
myStruct *structName = myFunction(0);
```

The function looks like

```
myStruct *myfunction(int x)
{

    if ( x == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

/*rest of code*/
}
```

Passing `NULL` or `0` BOTH trigger the `if (x== NULL)` statement and I can't figure out why. I need to return from the function on `NULL` but continue if the value is `0`. Any change made can only be made within the function itself.

Comment: `NULL` __is__ `0`.

Comment: NULL should be used with pointers, not integers.  There is no way that `int x` can be NULL, it is a value type.  You might try C# or Java, they're easier to start with than C as they give better error messages, and check for more error conditions.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to do an assignment. What you are trying to do cannot be done (since NULL and 0 are the same thing). Chances are you are reading the assignment incorrectly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Are there reasons to assign NULL instead of 0 to non-pointer variables?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/310826/are-there-reasons-to-assign-null-instead-of-0-to-non-pointer-variables)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate to ask at Stack Overflow. However, it would be closed as a duplicate of [What is the difference between NULL, '\0' and 0](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1296843/).

Comment: @Erik Eidt Agree `NULL` should be used with pointers, not integers.  Yet `NULL` is the _null pointer constant_.  When cast to `void*`, it is a null pointer.  `NULL` might have the value and type of `int` 0.  It is not necessarily a pointer.  It might be a pointer.  C is strange in this regard.

Comment: @tkausl In C, the macro `NULL` is not specified to be `0`.  Having `NULL` defined as `0` is one of a number of possibilities and it is certainly common that way.

Comment: Because C is a horrible weakly typed language.

Comment: You cannot pass a pointer into a function demanding `int` and expect reasonable behaviour. The fact that many C compilers allow `myfunction(NULL)` is a regrettable historical fact. You will notice that even they do not allow `void *p=NULL; myfunction(p);`.

Answer (score 12):

In C, `NULL` is a macro that expands either to `0` or `(void*)0` (or something that has a similar effect).

In the first case, you can not differentiate between `NULL` and `0`, because they are literally the same.
In the second case, your code will cause a compile error, because you can't compare an integer variable with a pointer.

Comment: "... NULL is a macro that expands either to 0 or ..." and " code will cause a compile error, because you can't compare an integer variable with a pointer" are contradictory.  If `NULL` expands to `0`, that is an `int` and certainty code  `if (NULL == ptr)` is not an error.  Even gcc generates a diagnostic, not an error, with a non-zero compare `if (42 == ptr)`

Comment: @chux: They are not contradictory because 0 is not an integer *variable*, but an integer *constant* (and a null-pointer constant as well). Besides, the reference to a compile error was for when `NULL` expands to `(void*)0`.

Comment: This is not true, `NULL` must _compare equal_ to `(void*)0`, but it can take any value. `if (x)` checks that `x` is non-null, but `(uintptr_t)NULL` does not have to be `0`.

Answer (score 4):

First some background ...

---

> The macros are `NULL` which expands to an implementation-defined *null pointer constant*; C11 §7.19 3

`NULL` typically is an integer constant 0 or `(void*)0` or the like.  It *may* have a different implementation or type - It could be `((int*) 0xDEADBEEF)` as strange as that may be.

`NULL` might be type `int`.  It might be type `void *` or something else.  The *type* of `NULL` is not defined.

---

When the *null pointer constant* `NULL` is cast to *any* pointer, is is a *null pointer*.  An integer `0` cast to a pointer is also a *null pointer*. A system could have many different (bit-wise)  *null pointers*.  They all *compare* equally to each other.  They all compare unequally to any valid object/function.  Recall this compare is done as pointers, not integers.

> An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type `void *`, is called a null pointer constant. If a null pointer constant is converted to a pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a null pointer, is guaranteed to compare unequal to a pointer to any object or function. C11 §6.3.2.3 3

```
int x;
if (&x == NULL) ... // this is false
```

---

So after all that chapter and verse how to distinguish `NULL` from `0`?

If the macro `NULL` is defined as an `int` `0` - it is game over - there is no difference between `0` and `NULL`.

If `NULL` is not an `int`, then code can use `_Generic()` to differentiate `NULL` and `0`.  This does not help OP's "Any change made can only be made within the function itself." requirement as that function accepts an `int` augment.

If `NULL` is an `int` that has a different bit-pattern than `0`, then a simple `memcmp()` can differentiate.

I suspect the whole reason for this exercise is to realize there is no *portable* method to distinguish `NULL` from `0`.

Answer (score 2):

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> **6.3.2.3 Pointers**
> ...
> 3     An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
> `void *`, is called a *null pointer constant*.
> <sup>66)</sup> If a null pointer constant is converted to a
> pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
> to a pointer to any object or function.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>66) The macro `NULL` is defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other headers) as a null pointer constant; see 7.19</sup>

In short, any 0-valued expression that appears in a pointer context is interpreted as `NULL`.

Comment: What is the significance of the term "constant" in "integer constant expression"? Does that mean if you had an integer variable `x` whose value was zero, that `x == NULL` is not guaranteed to be true? (Not that I think such an expression would be well-advised, even if it does work.)

Comment: @DominickPastore: A constant expression is something that can be evaluated at compile time - either a literal, an expression involving only literals, or a macro that expands to a literal or an expression involving only literals.  `NULL` expands to `(0)` or `((void *) 0)`.  I actually misspoke above when I said "any 0-valued expression" - a runtime `0` is not necessarily the same as a runtime *null pointer value*.  I've never worked on a platform where runtime `0` *wasn't* also a null pointer value, but my experience isn't that broad, either.